# Changing panel time for splunk dashboard studio irrespective of the global timing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard

Working over grid layout in splunk studio to created a dashboard, could not look for a way where we can customize the panel timing irrespective of the global duration of the dashboard.

For instance, if I want a panel to be showing data for last 15min but the global time remain fixed at 24 hours is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is preventing you from having a panel whose search includes an `earliest=-24h` clause?

eg the search might look like:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp earliest=-24h
<rest of search>
```